# jplayer ready event with playlist addon

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Further to my previous post about when/where to dynamically add items to a playlist, it appears that the jPlayer ready event handler function is not available when the Playlist add-on is used, as can be seen by a simple example:

```
$(function () {
        var MyPlayList = new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, [], {
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            supplied: "mp3"
        });
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                alert('here');
             }
        });
```

Whether this is because the event is not raised or because the jPlayer object is 'wrapped' by the PlayList is not clear, but either way it seems like a fairly fundamental restriction if this is indeed the case and there is no other way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
    $("#jplayer_id").bind($.jPlayer.event.loadeddata, function(event) { 
        // do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, $.jPlayer.event.ready it is more appropriate.

```
$("#jplayer_id").bind($.jPlayer.event.ready, function(event) { 
        // do stuff
});
```